VS 2022 not generating classes from WSDL
I have a WSDL here (created by SAP), and when I try to add it as a web reference, nothing is generated from it (I get an almost empty Reference.cs). When I use SVCUTIL "wsdlfilename.wsdl" I get the classes generated, however no SOAP client is created. Other WSDL files are working fine, just this one has an issue. What could be the problem?
I read several articles here, including this and this to no avail.

I check the wsdl and finding the SIDL schema is not found.  See if this helps : https://help.sap.com/docs/CARAB/5f6a0c50ac324b0395738c1ce0fe14c6/0c2f4851d5cd4b8f87eab3f8d9df717c.html
